# Is a Lipschitz function an open map?

Tags: real-analysis

The question randomly came up in my mind. I did a search, and I couldn't find anything relevant to this, so I am assuming this is false. Now, I am struggling to find a counterexample. Do you have any Lipschitz function that is not open?

Comment: Did you try with the most trivial example possible?

Comment: Yes, I was thought $\cos$ and $\sin$ would be a counter-example, but if I restrict the codomain to $[-1,1]$, then the result is still true. I thought about applying it on $\sqrt x$ with domain $[1, \infty]$.

Comment: More trivial still...

Comment: ah... ok. Sorry about the fuss.

Comment: Well, actually, if I take constant map and restrict the codomain, then the map is still open. So, does the result really depend on which codomain I take?

Comment: Your $\sin$ counterexample still works. You don't need a counterexample function that works for all domain restrictions. You just need a single function and a single domain where the function isn't open to have a counterexample.

Comment: @Arthur Got it. Thanks.